# Get the value of array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to get the value of the array based on the URL I can insert the value hello-world/ or hello-everybody/ based on the URL location into my link.

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var myArray = new Array( "hello-world/", "hello-everybody/" );
var isFound = false; 

for(var i=0,len=myArray.length;i<len;i++) {
  if(loc.indexOf(myArray[i])> -1) {
     isFound = true;
     break;
  }
} 

if(isFound) {
alert("href='//www.example.com/"+arrayvaluehere+"path/index.html")

}
});
```

I thought I could use this but I get this error **TypeError: b0.nodeName is undefined**

```
var arrayvaluehere = loc[$(myArray).val() - 1]
```

Comment: Why not `for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is because **loc** is a *string*, not an *array*. Also **.val()** returns a *string*, and therefore you can't **-1** from it.

Based on this, it's hard to tell what the answer is.  But I think maybe you could set **isFound = -1** initially and then **isFound = i** in the loop.  Then the last bit would be...

```
if(isFound>-1) {
  alert("href='//www.example.com/"+myArray[i]+"path/index.html");
}
```